# objective-c stringvalue from double

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, double, stringwithformat

I have the following code:

```
double d1 = 12.123456789012345;

NSString *test1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", d1]; // string is: 12.123457

NSString *test1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", d1]; // string is: 12.1235
```

How do I get a string value that is exactly the same as d1?

Answer (score 13):

It may help you to take a look at Apple's guide to [String Format Specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265).

```
%f  64-bit floating-point number 
%g  64-bit floating-point number (double), printed in the style of %e if the exponent is less than –4 or greater than or equal to the precision, in the style of %f otherwise
```

Also read up on [floating point (in)accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems), and, of course [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

If you really want the string to match the double exactly, then use `NSString` to encode it and call `doubleValue` when you want the value. Also take a look at `NSNumberFormatter`.

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
NSString *test1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.15f", d1];
```

Or simply go for the double as

```
NSString *test1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", d1];
```

Comment: @PengOne I fixed that for him, converted it to `%lf`, long floating point.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII My understanding is that `%lf` is only necessary when `scan`ing.

Comment: @PengOne actually, no, `%f` expects a 32-bit floating number, contrary to what the docs say, and `%lf` expects a 64-bit floating number.

Comment: %lf returns string "12.123457"

Comment: All you have to do is specify the number of decimals you want displayed by the .# before the type specifier.