# How to convert double to String?

Tags: c++, string, double

Can any body help me in converting a double value e.g. 0.000015 to string format in Xcode. so that i may use it as a string. 
In visual C++ we have to_string function but in Xcode it doesnt works.
Regards

Comment: Use `std::ostringstream`!

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495076/objective-c-stringvalue-from-double

Comment: ostringstream take char value. How ever i want to convert double or long double value to String.

Comment: _'ostringstream take char value'_ No, that's wrong! You can use the output `operator>>()` for any primitive type as usual!

Comment: How can i use this, can you give example forexample my code is given on           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21118842/how-to-convert-long-double-to-string-format-in-xcode-or-how-to-solve-error-us

Comment: How can i fix that, or convert that

Comment: Use the output operator as you would do with `std::cout`, and get the string you want using `std::ostringstream::str()` method.

Comment: when i use std::ostringstream::str(lr_value), it gives error, "call to non-static member function without an object argument"

Comment: See my answer how to use it. (There's also [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) available BTW).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your 'homebrew' `to_string()` function very easy using `std::stringstream`:

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string(T value)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << value;
    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot Bro... It worked, Sorry for late replying...just tried it now... thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you have a compiler supporting C++11, then [`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is what you want.

Comment: thanks but i used the upper answer, as in this case when i change it to c++11 it give me some other errors...so i used the first one...thanks and regards